# Not validating or sending email in MVC

Tags: validation, email, asp.net-mvc-4, gmail

Im trying to send email from my MVC 4 site and validate but nothing is happening this is the Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Net.Mail;


namespace DonsSolution.Controllers
{
public class SendMailerController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /SendMailer/

public ActionResult Index()
{
        return View();
 }
public static bool SendGmail(string subject, string content, string[] recipients,string         ........from)
    {
        bool success = recipients != null && recipients.Length > 0;

        if (success)
        {
            SmtpClient gmailClient = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("youremail@gmail.com","password")

            };


            using (MailMessage gMessage = new MailMessage(from, recipients[0], subject,     content))
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < recipients.Length; i++)
                    gMessage.To.Add(recipients[i]);

                try
                {
                    gmailClient.Send(gMessage);
                    success = true;
                }
                catch (Exception) { success = false; }
            }
        }
        return success;
    }
}
```

}

this is model

```
public class MailModel
    {
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "This is required")]
      public string From { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This is required")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This is required")]
    public string Body { get; set; }

   }
```

It is being passed in a partial view under the contact page

```
@model DonsSolution.Models.MailModel

<h2>Ask the Coach a question</h2>
<fieldset>
<legend>
Ask me a question?
</legend>
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <p>@Html.Label("From")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.From)</p>

    <p>@Html.Label("Subject") </p>
    <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Subject)</p>
    <p>@Html.Label("Body")</p>
    <p>@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Body)</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
}
```

I am very new to coding in general. I really need your help. I have tried so many different options, and nothing works. Please help.

Comment: You have two questions here.  It would be best to separate them into two questions; one for your validation, and the other for sending email.

Comment: as long as the email question is answered, that is the most important.